# Linux Version of Eclipse is freezing when trying to open binary files (with .bin extension)

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, swt

I had tried opening binary files of size 32MB. Eclipse (in Linux version) is freezing and I'm unable to perform any other operations (because of this hang in the Eclipse product).
I'm not even able to run other processes (like Task manger to exit the Eclipse IDE) which forces me to re-boot the system.

Comment: What are you expecting Eclipse to do with a .bin file?

Comment: Is there any limitation in size for the binary files to be opened ?
This issue exists only in Linux version of eclipse and not in windows versions..

Comment: What plugin are you expecting to deal with the .bin file? I am not clear if Eclipse has anything that deals with these files.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the EHEC plugin. [Here](http://sourceforge.net/p/ehep/bugs/) are two bug reports that sound similar to your post here...

Comment: Hi greg, In our projects, we are having binary files which is to be manipulated (by opening it in hex editor) and when i tried opening a file of size around 30 MB. eclipse is getting freezed

Comment: @ Baz: Yes, You are correct, I'm opening it in Hex Editor and those 2 bugs (in that link) was created by me

Comment: I think the problem is with SWT classes used in Linux. I compared the behavior by debugging in Windows as well as in Linux and found that the problem lies in the SWT classes. The code for SWT classes is entirely different in windows (when compared to Linux).
Is this an known issue in Linux ?

Comment: @greg-449: EHEP plugin deals with .bin files.

Comment: @Raguram I'm pretty sure that if the developers of the plugin can't help you, then other people who potentially don't even know the plugin won't be able to help either... Sorry.

Comment: @Baz: Thanks for your reply.. I raised this issue several months back but no action was taken by the plugin developer. If anything is to be done by my side surely i might have fixed it. Our customers are reporting issues with our product (developed on top of eclipse).

Comment: I just want to know if this is an known issue in Linux and if anyone has raised any issues related to this one ?

Comment: You say you have debugged the problem and think it is a SWT issue. So which SWT class do you think has a problem? Searching Eclipse bugs just for 'Linux freezing' is not going to produce anything useful, we need more detailed information.

Comment: @greg-449: Table.java (of SWT plugin) has a problem in computing the visible area of the editor. Method where the issue exists is getClientArea() of Table.java.

Comment: @greg-449 - May i know anyone who is well versed in SWT development ?

Comment: @greg-449 - Or is it possible to manipulate the SWT widgets for our-self and add them into our eclipse workspace.

Comment: SWT is open source so you can try but it would require a detailed knowledge of SWT and GTK to get anywhere. You can search the Eclipse [bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) to see if anything similar has been reported.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a problem in a particular plugin that you are using in your product, and that it is affecting your users.

If the plugin developer isn't helping you, your options are limited:

- You could "bug him" about it ... but this probably won't help.
- You could offer him (or someone else) money to fix the problem.
- You could try to find and fix the problem for yourself (assuming that the plugin is open source).
- You could identify an alternative plugin with the functionality you require.
- You could implement a replacement plugin yourself ... or pay someone else to do it.

From the technical perspective, I doubt that we can help you unless you explain in depth what the nature of the problem is, and what you have found.  On the face of it, it sounds like a scalability issue; i.e. the plugin is using an SWT widget that does not work with huge files.  If that is what the problem is, then the technical solution is probably to use the widget in a different way ... that avoids the issue.

Opening 30Mb binary files in an editor is kind of pathological.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The EHEP plugin is trying to access the SWT widgets which works as expected for small files, but not for huge files. 

ISSUE:
When trying to open a binary file (in Hex editor) in Debug mode the problem arises in the method updateVisibleTable() of HexTable.java which actually updates each row of the visible area (visible rows). While performing this, the visible rows are calculated wrongly inside the method determineVisibleRows() (for large sized .bin files the visibleRows.y has a value around lakhs (which is in-correct) and that's why the eclipse appears to be freezed.

Comment: "If that is what the problem is, then the technical solution is probably to use the widget in a different way ."

what do u mean by this ? How to use the widget in a different way ?
Can u help me in this...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Stephen C,
   Any update to my previous comment. I'd be very thankful if any solution is there for fixing this. If I'm not clear anywhere (in my previous comments) kindly let me know so that i may try to elaborate the issue precisely.

Comment: @Raguram - "How to use the widget in a different way ?"  Don't use it to load the entire file.  But my real message is that you / your company need to take the initiative in fixing this problem.  If necessary, find someone with deep understand of SWT, and >>pay<< them to develop an appropriate fix for you.

Comment: Stephen - Thanks for your reply.. Do paying is the only solution for fixing this problem ? Any possibility of manipulating the SWT classes (by our-self) and include them in our workspace ?

Comment: @Raguram - Sure.  If you have the expertise to figure out how to fix the problem, then what is stopping you?  However, if you are proposing to change SWT classes, that means that you will need to find a way to distribute those changes to your customers.

Comment: Stephen - I doubt how to create the jar file (org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_3.7.2.v3740f.jar) when the necessary changes are done.

Comment: The Eclipse build instructions are here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform-releng/Platform_Build

Comment: Hi Stephen - How to include our modified EHEP plugin in release mode (in the form of Binary) ? I've modified the EHEP plugin and want to have a look on how it behaves in release mode, so if any steps (or method) for integrating it into our product ?  

Thanks..

Comment: I searched in net for possible solutions but none was useful.

Comment: @Raguram - Sorry.  I don't know.